# Gulp sass compile replicating scss files

Tags: css, sass, gulp

I am using GULP to compile my scss files and trying trying to compile it down into a single `styles.css` file. However when I run `gulp sass` it converts the scss files down to css but also replicates them instead of compiling them all down into one single file.

**gulpfile.js**

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');

gulp.task('sass', function () {
  return gulp.src('./src/sass/**/*.scss')
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe(sass.sync({outputStyle: 'compressed'}).on('error', sass.logError))
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./src/css'));
});

gulp.task('sass:watch', function () {
  gulp.watch('./src/sass/**/*.scss', ['sass']);
});
```

**file structure**

```
 --gulpfile.js
    --src
      --css
      --sass
        --themes
          --module.scss
          --tm-1.scss
        --styles.scss
```

when i run `gulp sass` the css output ends up being:

```
--css
  --styles.css
  --themes
    --module.css
    --tm-1.css
```

which all I want here is one single `styles.css` file and cant seem to understand what I'm missing here.

Comment: I believe in order to do what you want, you may have to `import` the other (theme scss files) into your `styles.scss`. Essentially after all of the CSS in your `styles.scss`, you add `@import "themes/module";` and the same for `tm-1`. You can also prefix those files with an underscore `_module.scss` and `_tm-1.scss`. This should prevent them from being compiled into CSS files alone.

Answer (score 1):

I have fixed the issue by changing the line

`return gulp.src('./src/sass/**/*.scss')`

to:

`return gulp.src('./src/sass/styles.scss')`

Comment: Didn't know you could set it up so everything gets compiled without using `include` statements. Nice!

Comment: @disinfor You can't, this answer will not include any other code besides `styles.scss` unless there are import statements in `styles.scss`.  Perhaps that is intended I don't know.  If the final `styles.css` is supposed to include the `themes/` scss files then this code will not work without `import`'s.

Comment: @Mark then my initial comment on the question is correct. I thought I found out something new.